# Flash/AS3 security - passing movieclip reference to child swf?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, preloader

I'm seeing some strange behavior with respect to interactions between my preloader and main application classes (all AS3 / Flash CS4).  Roughly speaking, here's the flow of events:

1. Preloader.swf loads two things: main.swf, which is the main app, and assets for a custom object consisting of text and images, which are assembled into the object by the preloader from various URLs.
2. When load finishes, Preloader adds main.swf as a child.  Preloader then calls

   ```
   init(myCustomObject)
   ```

   on main.swf, where myCustomObject is a reference to the object assembled by the preloader during step 1 and

   ```
   public function init(customObject:CustomObject):void)
   ```

   is a method signature in Main.as. (Preload.as casts Main to an object of type * so as to be able to invoke arbitrary functions without fear of compile-time errors.)
3. Main.as is actually a container for the application itself, so it instantiates a

   ```
   new Application(customObject);
   ```

   passing along a reference to the customObject assembled by the preloader, and adds that as a child.

I've installed [thunderbolt](http://www.websector.de/blog/2008/06/15/10-tips-and-tricks-using-thunderbolt-as3/) so I can log messages as the application runs, and here's what I've determined is happening.  The instantiation of the Application object in step 3 is what's causing trouble; for some reason, the statement
`myMainApplication = new Application(customobj);` in Main.as is throwing a lovely `#1009` error, which usually indicates a null pointer reference or something similar.

The strange thing is that I've added some logging to `Application.as`, and it seems to be receiving the reference to `customObject` without a problem; calling `toString()` on the `customObject` in `Application`'s constructor returns exactly the expected data.

In other words, the statement `myMainApplication = new Application(customobj);` in Main.as seems to be succeeding and failing at the same time.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `myMainApplication = new Application(customobj);` seemed to be succeeding and failing at the same time is that I didn't completely understand the way the `try/catch` blocks operate in AS3.  There was a null pointer exception being thrown in a subroutine to `Application`'s constructor, occurring after the code in which `Application` checks to ensure it's receiving a reference to customobj.  This error was being caught by the `try/catch` block surrounding the instantation of `Application` in `Main`, as it was the nearest enclosing error-checking code.

Hopefully my mistake will save someone else for making a similar one!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your casting accross application domains, so although the types are the same files, in the memory of each application domain they are 2 separate concrete types.  There are many ways to get around this, possibly starting with loading into a sibling application domain instead of a child domain, or not bothering with the cast and explicitly calling the function in question on the untyped object.

[WeLoveAppDomain](http://www.welove72.com/blog/tag/as3-application-domain/) should be of some assistance if it is in fact this issue.    Can you put together the smallest possible example to demonstrate this failure for us to de-construct?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Global Security Settings in Flash Player allows local access to the directory.

Try this. Go to Publish Settings - Local playback security - choose "access network only." Flash CS4 default is "Access local files only" which it may not like. I hope this is useful.

See:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Security.html

Answer (score 0):

I think we'll need to see more code, but to start: "customobj" ... where are you defining that? You refer to "customObject" everywhere else. Is that a typo? If that exact statment is throwing the error then "customobj" is most likely null.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FlexBuilder/FlashDevelop or the flash IDE? 
Also, how are you setting up your Preloader?

If you build your app with FlexBuilder/FlashDevelop, did you specify the frame start in your compiler options?